# install Kali on side partition with systemd-boot

Tags: debian, installation, kali-linux, bootloader

On my macbook I have installed arch linux following the [installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide).

I chose [systemd-boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-boot) as the boot loader. I have an EFI partition at `/dev/sda1` that stores `systemd-boot`and so.

Everything is fine, I can boot either on my macos partition or archlinux.

Now, I want to install Kali linux on an other partition. I tried the graphical install and when it comes to set up disks, I can set up a new partition for the new `/`of the system.

But as for `/boot`, I am afraid that setting it to `/dev/sda1` will overwrite data or reformat the whole partition, in such a way that will make my previous `systemd-boot` unusable.

What could be done to install Kali with my setup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Kali using the installer and skip bootloader installation. Say Kali is installed at `/dev/sda4`

Then I boot on my Arch partition and mount `/dev/sda4` on `/mnt`. You can find in `/mnt/boot` the kernel and initrd files. You just have to copy this to your EFI partition. Here the EFI partition is mounted at `/boot`.

Then do

```
cp /mnt/boot/vlinuz_xxx /boot/vlinuz_xxx 
cp /mnt/boot/initrd_xxx /boot/initrd_xxx
```

And put the corresponding systemd config file in `/boot/loader/entries/kali.conf`using `quiet` as option for the kernel.

Comment: You probably want to empty the Kali `/boot` and mount the the ESP on it as well (add it to Kali's fstab).

Comment: Indeed, that way, you only have one kernel file. Also it helps `apt-get`to update kernel and so.